# $S:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $v\mapsto \alpha v$ for a fixed $\alpha\ne 0$ (real)

Tags: linear-algebra

$S:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $v\mapsto \alpha v$ for a fixed $\alpha\ne 0$ (real),$T$ be another linear map such that $\beta=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a set of linearly indipendent eigen vectors of $T$,Then

1. The matrix of $T$ wrt $\beta$ is diagonal

   True by definition of diagonalization of a Lin Map,
2. The matrix of $T-S$ wrt $\beta$ is diagonal.

   I have no idea.
3. The matrix of $T$ wrt $\beta$ is not necessary diagonal but upper triangular.

   Here I am bit confused,I never saw any result like this
4. The matrix of $T$ wrt $\beta$ is diagonal but The matrix of $T-S$ wrt $\beta$ is not diagonal.

   well, confused again.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What is the representation of $S$ with respect to **any** basis?

Comment: It will be a scaler matrix $\alpha I$ definitely

Comment: What is a scalar matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You answered that
2. $S$ is diagonal in any base, as it's just $αI$. So in a base $β$ where $T$ is diagonal, of course $T-S$ is diagonal. Note that $T-S$ may not be invertible.
3. See 1.
4. See 2.

Comment: so only 1,2 are true statements right?

Comment: right. as 3 is incompatible with 1 and 4 is incompatible with 2.